# How to pass an Activity in an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to implement the delegate pattern for inform to the UI of the process of a async operation. So I have an interface like that:

```
public interface UpdateLibraryDelegate {
    public void startDownloadingLibrary();
    public void endDownloadingLibrary();
    public void processingLibrary(int progress);
    public void endProcessingLibrary();
}
```

I have an Activity :

```
public class HomeActivity implements UpdateLibraryDelegate{

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         ...
          Intent libraryIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
          /*Here is where the problem is*/
          libraryIntent.putExtra(UPDATE_LIBRARY_DELEGATE, this);
         ...
   }

  /*Methods of the interface*/
  ...
  /**/
}
```

The problem obviously is that I can't send my activity in the intent since it isn't either Serializable or Parcelable. Is there any way to send the activity with the Intent? It is stupid what I am trying to do and there is a more reasonable way to do that? I am completely new on Android...

Thanks!

Comment: You should never pass activities around.  There's a lot of material on why this is on the web, but in any case, you do not need to.  However, you haven't said *what* you are trying to do.  Are you trying to pass some values from HomeActivity to MyService?  BTW, you must also extend Activity - `public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements UpdateLibraryDelegate{`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the **AsyncTask** class to perform async operations.

Watch [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for the class usage.

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example) for an example.

Comment: I finally solve this avoiding use a intent and use an AsyncTask instead.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to send the activity with the Intent?

No.

> It is stupid what I am trying to do and there is a more reasonable way to do that?

The contract pattern is perfectly fine, just not for activity<->service communication using the command pattern. That is a loose-coupling pattern, which runs counter to the contract (what you are calling the delegate) pattern.

Moreover, if you are using the command pattern with a service, the reason for having the service in the first place is because the activity can go away, while the service wraps up its bit of work. That is why loose coupling is used here.

The more typical approach for services is to use message passing:

- `LocalBroadcastManager`
- a third-party event bus, like [Square's Otto](https://github.com/square/otto%E2%80%8E)
- a `Messenger`
- etc.

to have the service raise events that the activity can subscribe to, if the activity exists.

If the service will only be around while the activity is, you may wish to reconsider why you have the service in the first place. If there are legitimate needs for the service, you could use the binding pattern (`bindService()`), in which case you can *carefully* use your contract/delegate pattern.